# I have problem with writing integrals..(size issue)

Tags: size, integral

[image]

i want to write integral like above image,

but i dont know why i have to write like this

[image]

I use Pages on MacOS.

Comment: "Pages on Mac"? I think that's off topic for this site.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about Pages which is off-topic